# How to dockerize or build puppeteer js?

Tags: puppeteer

I have a simple puppeteer code that uses some ES6 and is run by the help of Babel.

Currently my `Package.json` points to

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --no-warnings ./src/index.js"
}
```

and I wonder if there is a way I can build all files into one final JS or somehow package it instead of having to deal with all the files to run or typing everything allover again.

Comment: What do you mean by "typing everything allover again", typing `yarn dev`?

Comment: node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --no-warnings ./src/index.js should be typed again since there is es6.